# "Inverse" of Double Suspension Theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

My question arose when I was working on a research problem. It is as following:

Let $M$ be a homology manifold whose homology groups are the same as a sphere. Assume further that the double suspension of $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere. Is $M$ homeomorphic to the suspension of a homology sphere?

Edition: Is $M$ homeomorphic to either suspension of a homology sphere or homeomorphic to a homology sphere.

Answer (score 4):

No. The suspension of a connected space is simply connected, and M might not be.

Comment: @ Dan Petersen. You are right. I edited my question.